# Base64 в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, base64

Как не указывая размеры Канваса вставить в него изображение base64 чтобы оно гарантировано вместилось полностью, а затем отмасштабировать Канвас по определённым размерам?

Comment: никак, ты должен указать размеры canvas

Comment: может тогда лучше использовать svg. а канвас наложить сверху, если он нужен.

Comment: чёт я не понял, размер канвы всегда известен, даже если Вы его не задавали - считайте его